# jquery mobile: Selectmenu need to select two times

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have one input fields with an autocomplete (`#street`) and one with a selectmenu (`#number`). If you select a street the selectmenu with the numbers get's filled from a local array. Works fine in FF and Chrome, but not on the iPhone.

The problem is that the selectmenu does not work the first time I select something. I can see the options, select something but this is ignored. Let's say I select `3` and it keeps number `1`. If I try again it works.

The problem appears only if I change street first. If I don't change the street the number select works just fine. So I guess the select menu is not fully created or something like this.

HTML

```
<div>
    <label for="street">Bitte wählen Sie Ihre Straße:</label>
    <input name="steet" id="street" style="z-index: 3; position: relative;" />
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <label for="number">Hausnummer:</label>
    <select name="number" id="number" ></select>
</div>
```

JS to fill `#number` after `#street` was changed:

```
    $('#street').autocomplete({
        source: ELW.data.streets,
        minLength: 3,
        change: function(event, ui)
        {
            // alle Hausnummern löschen
            $("#number option").remove();
            $('#number').val('');

            // Straße ausgewählt?
            var numbers = ELW.address.getNumbers($('#street').val());
            if (numbers)
            {
                // Hausnummern einfügen
                $.each(numbers, function(index, value){
                    value = value.split(':');
                    $("<option/>").val(value[0] + ':' 
                         + value[1]).text(value[1]).appendTo("#number");
                });
            }
            // update
            $("#number option:first").attr('selected', true);
            $('#number').selectmenu("refresh");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I found a solution.

You can prevent the iPhone from using it's native menu wheel by setting `data-native-menu="false"`. With the alternative select menu from jquery, it works fine:

```
<select name="number" id="number" data-native-menu="false" ></select>
```

Found it in the [manual](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/docs/forms/selects/custom.html).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try in Safari ? Safari should give you the solution for the problem you are facing on iphone.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! It works fine in Safari, too. But Safari does not have this selection wheel that pops up on the iPod. I think the Problem is related to this.

Comment: But Safari was a greate advice. Solved some other problemes this way! ;)

Comment: Nice to know :) Its actually difficult to get to root of the issue but small steps help.

Comment: You are lucky! Because of the bounty would be [wasted otherwise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120242/what-happens-to-a-bounty-if-you-accept-your-own-answer) I better give it to you. Have fun!